# Dyanmic VBA code for changing the vba when a sheet name is changed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a vba code which specifies particular sheet names to look at for example sheet 2,

But what if, someone forgot to change the sheet name to sheet2, can I add a piece of dynamic code to automatically change the vba code for which ever the sheet name is called? for example the second sheet in from the left.

Code Module 1:

```
Sub Calculation()
 Range("P2:P800").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents

Dim dict1 As Object
Dim c1 As Variant, k As Variant
Dim currWS As Worksheet
Dim i As Double, lastRow As Double, tot As Double
Dim number1 As Double, number2 As Double, firstRow As Double

Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trade data")

'get last row withh data in Column A
lastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

'put unique numbers in Column A in dict1
c1 = Range("M2:V" & lastRow)
For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
    If c1(i, 1) <> "" Then
        'make combination with first 4 characters
      dict1(Left(c1(i, 1), 4) & "," & Left(c1(i, 8), 4) & "," & Left(c1(i,
    6), 10) & "," & Left(c1(i, 10), 7)) = 1
    End If
Next i

'loop through all the numbers in column A
For Each k In dict1.keys
    number1 = Split(k, ",")(0)
    number2 = Split(k, ",")(1)
    tot = 0
    firstRow = 0

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If k = Left(currWS.Range("M" & i).Value, 4) & "," & 
        Left(currWS.Range("T" & i).Value, 4) & "," & currWS.Range("R" &
     i).Value & "," & (currWS.Range("O" & i).Value) Then
            If firstRow = 0 Then
                firstRow = i
            End If
            tot = tot + currWS.Range("W" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
    currWS.Range("P" & firstRow) = tot
Next k

Call Consolidate
Call SingleTradeMove
End Sub
```

Module 2 code:
    Sub SingleTradeMove()

```
 Dim wsTD As Worksheet
 Set wsTD = Worksheets("Trade data")

 Sheets("UnMatching").Range("A2:AK600").ClearContents

 With wsTD

 lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To lastRow


If Left(.Cells(i, "M"), 4) <> Left(.Cells(i, "T"), 4) _
    Or .Cells(i, "O") <> .Cells(i, "V") _
    Or .Cells(i, "R") <> .Cells(i, "Y") Then

       .Cells(i, "J").EntireRow.Copy _
           Destination:=Sheets("UnMatching").Range("A" &   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

     End If

 Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: post the code you have and we can help make it work. hard to be specific without an example

Comment: This type of code is completely out of my scope of knowledge but would be enlightening if someone could answer this.

Comment: Sure I will do this now

Comment: Move your code to a `Sub` that has a parameter of type `Worksheet` (`Sub DoThings(ByVal w As Worksheet)`). Pass whatever to it each time, such as `Worksheets("sheet2")` or `Worksheets(2)`.

Comment: I have added my code, would you guys be able to advise?

Comment: Will it always be the 2nd worksheet in the workbook? Or can it be anywhere? If you want to make sure it processes a "particular" sheet each time you have to have *some sort of anchor* for that sheet. Whether it's `Name` or `Index (nth sheet in workbook)` or even `something specific in a sheet cell`

Comment: It will always be the second sheet

Comment: but to remove the necessity of changing to UnMatching each time would be great to have this as "whatever is the second sheet" use that name

Comment: `Worksheets(2).Range("A1")` for example @George

Comment: Use the Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) in your code. While it *can* be changed, it is highly unlikely that it will be.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help I believe my question has now been answered

Comment: @ Jeeped props for code name, great tip

Answer (score 2):

Building off ian0411's answer since I can not comment yet. You can also change this name to short hand. I always change mine to CN and then an abbreviation or something short enough its not a hassle to type out. In the example the sheet name in excel is BlueMoon. So I used CNBM in VBA. This gives a reference to the sheet, and the sheet name on excel's side can be changed without effecting your code. To change the name, click the sheet you want to name in the properties box. Then below that alter the (Name) option.

[image: Image of VBA properties]

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a sheet named "Work data" and you programmed as `Sheets("Work data")`.  To make this dynamic, you can use the name before the parenthese that when you launch your Visual Basic editor.

[image: Visual Basic Editor Screenshot]

For example, you have this code:

```
Sheets("Work data").Select
```

Now you can change to this:

```
Sheet1.Select
```

And this way, no matter how users changed the sheet name, it will always work.  BUT please remember, the Sheet1 can be also changed but that can only be done inside Visual Basic editor properties.  You can password protected the VBA so no one can accidentally alter it.